# Proxy action for user-agent blocking with regular expressions not blocking

Tags: firewall, regex, watchguard

I have a server behind a Watchguard XTM firewall and want to block incoming RESTClients who has certain user-agents in their request headers. I have implemented several rules to do this:

**List image**[image: (http://s14.postimg.org/6y9lsq2ep/2015_02_18_13_15_01_Edit_HTTP_Proxy_Action_Confi.png)]

Here's one example of how I implemented them:

**Regex implementation**[image: http://s27.postimg.org/wnzy8g1s3/2015_02_18_13_15_53_Edit_Header_Fields_Rule.png]

For practice, I would like to use the following regex to block incoming request headers with User-Agents like:

```
binlar|casper|checkprivacy|cmsworldmap|comodo|curious|diavol|doco
```

But none of my rules has any actions when I test them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not look like proper regular expression syntax. Try it like this:

> User-Agent:.*(binlar|casper|checkprivacy|cmsworldmap|comodo|curious|diavol|doco).*

That *should* match all User Agents that have one of those strings in them.